# How to accept files and generate archive file in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that accepts two files (File1 and File2) on the command line and generate an archive file which contains all these files

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_SIZE 300

struct header {
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char size[12];
};

typedef struct header HEADER;
typedef HEADER * HEADER_PTR;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    int headerSize = sizeof(HEADER);
    FILE * archive; 
    archive = fopen("File1.txt", "File2.txt");

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char * filename = argv[i];

        FILE * fptr;

        fptr = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (fptr == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
        }

        HEADER_PTR FILE_HEAD = malloc(headerSize);

        memset(FILE_HEAD->name, 0, NAME_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        memset(FILE_HEAD->size, 0, 12 * sizeof(char));
        snprintf(FILE_HEAD->name, NAME_SIZE, "%s", filename);
        fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
        sprintf(FILE_HEAD->size, "%ld", ftell(fptr));
        fwrite(FILE_HEAD, headerSize, 1, archive);

        fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while (!feof(fptr)) {
            fputc(fgetc(fptr), archive);
        }

        fclose(fptr);
    }
        fclose(archive);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem: It is not generating the archive file...

Comment: `fopen` accepts a single filename because it opens one file. You want the filename of whatever you decide to name your archive there, not two filenames.

Comment: Delete those two lines `FILE * archive;  archive = fopen("File1.txt", "File2.txt", "a+");` and call your program using `./program File1.txt File2.txt`

Comment: look at the man page for [`fopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). It accepts only 2 arguments, you're giving it 3, just as the error indicates.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I will get the error of 'archive' undeclared

Comment: @yano hi, i have kept it to only 2 arguments... now its not generating the archive file

Comment: Ah, you want to write to those files? Then you need to open them in a loop as you ar doing with the `argv` files, but switch to `FILE * archive[2];` and `fwrite(FILE_HEAD, headerSize, 1, archive[i])`